# Browsers to accept a self-signed certificate

Tags: https, security, security-certificate, openssl

I have created a self signed certificate like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPIRE=3650

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then

  EXPIRE=$2  

fi

mkdir -p $1
cd $1

openssl genrsa 2048 > $1.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days $EXPIRE -key $1.key > $1.cert
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -text < $1.cert > $1.info

cat $1.cert $1.key > $1.pem
chmod 400 $1.key $1.pem
```

And configured my apache vhost to use this cert.

Now I wonder which file I have to import in a clients storage (Chrome or Firefox) to tell the browser everything is ok!

Comment: Nowadays browsers do not like certificates without a SAN extension, so you may need to add one.

Answer (score 2):

**New answer** following your comment and reading again your post:

I see that you created first a private key which you used to generated a self-signed certificate. You used the keyword -new which thing means that during this generation process, there is also a [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) which is created.

You asked about which files to store where. In reality you need to set:

- **Server**: The private key, the certificate **and** the CSR file on your server. So in your case, the file `1.pem` contains already the private key and the certificate.
- **Client**: Install (only) the certificate on your browser.

---

**Old answer** (kept for further useful information):

Unfortunately, you are in a wrong path and it is useless to continue because any person visiting reading again your website will read notice that his client (browser) that warning him/her that the Certificate Authority (CA) who issued the certificate is not trusted. post:

I mean your certificate is self-signed and thus may be see that you trust it but it rather needs to be trusted by created first a central authority.

Do not rely on users to accept and load your self-signed certificate private key which will rather be an obstacle to attract audience for your website.

Most hosting providers such as AWS and OVH offer you used to install, on their behalf, generated a free but effective SSL self-signed certificate called [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) which is renewable every 3 months (for security and other reasons). If your hosting provider does not offer you this option (check the [list](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/web-hosting-who-support-lets-encrypt/6920) of hosting providers that offer it), then you can install yourself there is also a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate with or without a shell access to your server.

Comment: I know that, this sites are my own services I am using. No one else. So I wondered if it is enough to import one of the created certificate parts.

Comment: @Pascal sorry for the misunderstand and the late reply. I edited

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meanwhile I have tried 'Let's encrypt' and I am very excited ;)